# Add socket emit from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a new socket event handler in an online browser game I play so I can send data between players who have the same userscript installed.

The game uses socket.io and here's what I've done so far: I added a user-side socket.on handler, like this:

```
game.socket.on("hello", function() { console.log("hello there") })
```

I did this on two players that are connected to the same game, but when I do this:

```
game.socket.emit("hello")
```

Only the player who sent out the emit logs out `hello there`.

My guess is that the server-side doesn't have a handler that emits the event with name `hello`. Is there a way I can add that without access to the server-side code, or circumvent it and send the data directly to the other players?

Comment: You will have to show a larger context of your code.  `game.socket.emit("hello")` will only send a message to one socket endpoint.  If that's endpoint is your server and you expect your server to then send that message out to other users, you will need to add code to the server to listen for that message and then send it out to other players when it is received.  socket.io is a client to server connection.  You cannot send directly from one client to another in socket.io (or in websocket).  Instead, you have to send to the server and have the server forward it on to some other client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will add a bit and turn my comment into an answer:

A socket.io connection is a connection between client and server.  From the client, all you can do on that connection is send to the server.  Thus `game.socket.emit("hello")` will only send a message to the server.

If you want your server to then send that message out to other users, you will need to add code to the server to listen for that message and then send it out to other players when it is received. socket.io is a client to server connection.

You cannot send directly from one client to another in socket.io (or in websocket which socket.io is based on). Instead, you have to send to the server and have the server forward it on to some other client.

Answer (score 2):

Socket.io have introduced **room** ([check](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#socketjoinnamestring-fnfunctionsocket)),You can send your message from client and use server side to emit this message to all the room members,considering your room id is *room_one*:

**Client:**

```
var socket = io();  
socket.on('connect',function(){      
      socket.emit('join','room_one');
      socket.emit('room_message',{hello:'hello'});
});   
socket.on('room_message',function(data){
      console.log(data);
})
```

**Server:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){    
    socket.on('join',function(room){
        socket.join(room);
    });
    socket.on('room_message', function(data) {        
        io.to('room_one').emit('room_message',{world:'world'});
    });
});
```

wish this would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to display the current users in a room to all connected sockets:

**server side**

```js
socket.join(user.room);
io.to(user.room).emit('roomData',{room:user.room, users: getUsersInRoom(user.room)});
```

**client side**

```js
socket.on('roomData',(data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    currentUsers.innerHTML='${data.users.length} Users Online in ${data.room} Room'
});
```